# octave on OSX Yosemite, print outputs doc, but graph is solid black

Tags: octave, osx-yosemite

I used homebrew to install octave, rebooted machine.  I can run plots successfully and see the graphs render normally.  When I go to print them, the document saves with the legend and axes, but the body of the graph is solid black.  I have tried this with png, pdf and jpg formats - all the same.
I do get a message that fig2dev binary is not available.  I have searched for what I am missing but seem to have everything installed from homebrew that octave needs.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem. Installing fig2dev made the error message disappear but the body of the graph was still black. As suggested by ordrisci, reverting to the old version of gnuplot worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is a problem with gnuplot 5 and Macs (see the [bug report](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44458)). I was able to solve this by doing as suggested in the link and downgrading to gunplot version 4.6.6

```
brew switch gnuplot 4.6.6
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) answer has lots of good info on installing specific versions of software in homebrew.